# Dynamic created element not change CSS no first click only

Tags: jquery, ajax

When i press for first time  button shared-products-send i see data is send and load but when modal is open body still display none , if i press second time body style is change and content is visible why first time do not changing style ? what is wrong and how will i fix it ?

```
// each button create his own modal-body , on click load and display current button-> modal-body and hide others
$('.shared-products-send').on('click', function() {
var id = $(this).data("id");
var currentElement = $(this);

if (!$(this).hasClass("pressed")) {
$.ajax({
  url: 'test.php',
  type: 'post',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: id,
  beforeSend: function(){
    $(currentElement).addClass("pressed");
  },
  success: function(json) {

    $('#sharedProducts .modal-content').append('<div class="modal-body" id="'+id+'" data-id="'+id+'" style="display: none"><div class="row"></div></div>');

    $.each(json.result, function(key, value) {
      html += '<p>'+ json.result[key].price +'</p>';
    $('#sharedProducts .modal-body#'+id+' .row').append(html);

    });
  }
 });
}
$('.modal-body[data-id="'+id+'"]').css('display', 'block');
$('.modal-body').not('.modal-body[data-id="'+id+'"]').css('display', 'none');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fix the issue with DOMSubtreeModified

```
$("body").on('DOMSubtreeModified', function() {
$('.shared-products-send').on('click', function(){
  var id = $(this).data("id");
  $('.modal-body[data-id="'+id+'"]').css('display', 'block');
  $('.modal-body').not('.modal-body[data-id="'+id+'"]').css('display', 'none');
});
});
```